# .txt File from Mac not converting properly

Tags: text-processing, osx, raspbian, nano

I have a .txt file from my Mac that when I send it over to my Raspberry Pi running Raspbian and open it in nano it converts weirdly. 
Example:

Text file in Mac OSX:

```
http://welcome.hp.com/country/us/en/prodserv/servers.html
http://www8.hp.com/us/en/products/data-storage/overview.html
```

Text file in Raspbian:

```
Servers & Blades
Storage
http://welcome.hp.com/country/us/en/prodserv/servers.html^Mhttp://www8.hp.com/us/en/products/data-storage/overview.html
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It looks like your file has a mixture of different types of line endings. Please post the output of `od -t x1 thefile.txt` (the output should be the same on both machines). Do you care about which type of line ending is used, or do you just want an ordinary text file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed -i 's/\r/\n/g' thefile.txt
```

"classic" macos used `\r` as the end-of-line character. *nix uses `\n`