# cat vs. view and execution of file containing diacritics uploaded from Windows to Linux with WinSCP

Tags: linux, shell-script, sftp, special-characters, character-special-files

I have a `DE_CopyOldToNew.sh` file that was created in Windows. The file is then uploaded to Linux using WinSCP. The file contains a whole bunch of cp commands that copies files to a new folder with a new filename being assigned. The commands contain folders and files with diacritics like     `Gewährleistungsbürgschaft`.
When I do a `cat DE_CopyOldToNew.sh` I noticed that the diacritics are displayed in a "corrupted" way like `Gew▒hrleistungsb▒rgschaft`. When I do a `view DE_CopyOldToNew.sh` then the diacritics are displayed as they should be, like `Gewährleistungsbürgschaft`. When I execute my script I am getting `cp: cannot stat` errors and the diacritics in the folders and files are displayed as `Gew\344hrleistungsb\374rgschaft`.
I have uploaded the file using `binary` as well as `text` and I have also performed a `dos2unix DE_CopyOldToNew.sh`.
When I copy the content of my script in Windows and paste it into a new file in Linux then I am able to run the new script without issues.
What is causing the uploaded version to be "corrupted" (for a lack of a better word)?

Comment: Which editor are you using? It's probably saving as latin1 / iso8859 / cp1252 instead of utf8. When saving as UTF-8, if there is an option to save with or without Byte-Order-Mark, pick UTF-8 without BOM. You can also use `iconv` to convert charsets. `file` might display the charset (but it's a guess).

Comment: I am creating the file with VBA using ADO Stream Writer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your file is written in one of the ISO-8859 encodings (probably Windows CP1252 or ISO-8859-15), whereas your Linux-based system is set up to expect a UTF-8 encoding.

You can verify this easily enough:

```
# Original text
printf 'Gew\344hrleistungsb\374rgschaft\n'
Gew�hrleistungsb�rgschaft

# What character set
printf 'Gew\344hrleistungsb\374rgschaft\n' | file -
/dev/stdin: ISO-8859 text

# Transcoded text
printf 'Gew\344hrleistungsb\374rgschaft\n' | iconv -f iso-8859-15 -t utf-8
Gewährleistungsbürgschaft

# What character set
printf 'Gew\344hrleistungsb\374rgschaft\n' | iconv -f iso-8859-15 -t utf-8 | file -
/dev/stdin: UTF-8 Unicode text
```

Solutions?

1. Create your file as UTF-8 on the source system (Windows applications support this character set)
2. Downgrade your Linux-based system back to ISO-8859. Not recommended (but possible)
3. Convert the file once it's been transferred:

   ```
   iconv -f iso-8859-15 -t utf-8 DE_CopyOldToNew.sh >DE_CopyOldToNew.sh.tmp &&
       mv -f DE_CopyOldToNew.sh.tmp DE_CopyOldToNew.sh
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the response @Chris Davies. 
I have recreated my file in Windows  in UTF-8 and uploaded it again.
`$ file DE_CopyOldToNew.sh
DE_CopyOldToNew.sh: UTF-8 Unicode (with BOM) text, with very long lines, with CR line terminators` 
When doing a `cat  DE_CopyOldToNew.sh` the copy commands are now all starting on a new line. When doing a `view DE_CopyOldToNew.sh` the commands are all wrapped and delimited with a `^M` like `<copy command 1>^M<copy command 2>`. When executing the script I am getting `./DE_CopyOldToNew.sh: line 1: cp: command not found`

Comment: Your file is still in the wrong format. Can you create it on the target system instead? So much easier. If not then [How can I remove the BOM from a UTF-8 file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/381230/100397) and [txt File from Mac not converting properly](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/205760/100397)

Comment: In my VBA code I have removed the `UTFStream.LineSeparator = 10` line of code and in Linux I performed a `dos2unix DE_CopyOldToNew.sh`. This solved the problem.

Comment: If you put the line separator code back in, it'll probably work without needing `dos2unix`